# Does an adjectival following a verb complement the verb or the subject?

Tags: poetry, secondary-predicates

> My feet they are sore, and my limbs they are weary;
>   Long is the way, and the mountains are wild;
>   Soon will the twilight close **moonless and dreary**
>   over the path of the poor orphan child. (Jane Eyre)

Ought the highlighted part of the sentence be called complement for subject, or complement for verb?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SHORT VERSION:
It’s not a *complement* of either sort, but a literary ellipsis.

LONG VERSION:
I think that under the surface this is essentially the same situation as that you brought up in your earlier question on [ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/102666/), “Her teeth gleamed white against the tanned skin of her face.”

*(That, by the way, is by no means a criticism: both are very interesting questions, and I am glad to see the matter arise on both sites.)*

I am not comfortable with calling *moonless and dreary* here a ‘complement’ of any sort. Although Mistu4u's characterization of *close* as a linking verb in this context has good authority, this is stretching the concept. *Moonless and dreary* does not ‘complete’ the sense of *close*: *Soon will the twilight close over the path ...* is an entirely acceptable sentence without it. As I wrote at the other question, if you treat this as a *complement*,  “***any*** verb [may be said to] license a secondary complement of this sort; intransitive verbs license subject complements, transitive verbs license object complements in the active voice, subject complements in the passive voice.” In that case, you’ve essentially redefined *complement* to a point where it means very little that is useful.

Robusto’s answer at the other question, that it is “a modicative adjunct, for it describes the state brought about by the verb”, comes closer to the facts in the case. But of course John Lawler warned us there against using *adjunct*, which means different things to different people. In any case, there is a big difference between *Her teeth gleamed white* and *Twilight will close moonless...*: *White* describes *teeth*, but *moonless and dreary* does not describe any entity actually present in the sentence.

What you have here is in fact a very powerful ellipsis, which implies an entire sentence in the phrase *moonless and dreary*. Prosaically expressed:

> Soon the twilight will close, *and a moonless and dreary night will descend* over the path ...

When you get to that sort of poetic concentration, ordinary syntactical analysis has to throw up its hands and admit defeat.

Comment: Fine explanation.

Answer (score 1):

This is a **Subject Complement**. If we write the sentence in simple way:

> Soon the twilight will close moonless and dreary........

Here *will close* is a *[linking verb](http://www.usingenglish.com/glossary/linking-verb.html)* which links the subject *twilight* with it's quality, an adjective i.e. *moonless and dreary*.

Also, from the idea of [Subject Complement](http://www.noslangues-ourlanguages.gc.ca/bien-well/fra-eng/grammaire-grammar/comple-eng.html):

It completes our idea of the subject of a sentence by giving us more information about it. It is an adjective, too. Here *moonless and dreary* completes our idea about the twilight.

[Verb Complement](http://public.wsu.edu/~mejia/Verb_3.htm) on the other hand requires two verbs, one verb is used as the object of another verb. But here in the sentence there is only one verb: *close*.

Hence it is not a *verb complement*.